# Can I use Dominance analysis (using r package domir for instance) with a negative binomial (nb.glm)?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, importance

I want to examine the relative importance of the predictors in my model.

I know the `domir` package in `R` allows for the examination of relative importance for `glm` but my model is a `nb.glm`.

Is there a way that I can use to examine the relative importance in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so long as a useful $R^2$ metric can be chosen.  One such metric is the deviance $R^2$ (Cameron & Windmeijer, 1996).

I provide an example with the recommended metric below.

```
> MASS::glm.nb(cyl ~ am + drat + wt, data = mtcars)

Call:  MASS::glm.nb(formula = cyl ~ am + drat + wt, data = mtcars, init.theta = 575132.5129, 
    link = log)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           am         drat           wt  
    2.04291      0.09733     -0.23111      0.16930  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
Null Deviance:      16.57 
Residual Deviance: 5.988    AIC: 132.6
Warning messages:
1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached
2: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached

> domir::domir(
     cyl ~ am + drat + wt,
     
     \(fml) {
     
         MASS::glm.nb(fml, data = mtcars) |>
         performance::r2_kullback(adjust = FALSE)
     
     }
 )


Overall Value:      0.6387408 

General Dominance Values:
     General Dominance Standardized Ranks
am          0.09366876    0.1466460     3
drat        0.22793619    0.3568524     2
wt          0.31713586    0.4965016     1

Conditional Dominance Values:
     Subset Size: 1 Subset Size: 2 Subset Size: 3
am        0.2694899   0.0006728092     0.01084360
drat      0.4824463   0.1349402416     0.06642206
wt        0.5719815   0.2241399125     0.15528618

Complete Dominance Designations:
             Dmnated?am Dmnated?drat Dmnated?wt
Dmnates?am           NA        FALSE      FALSE
Dmnates?drat       TRUE           NA      FALSE
Dmnates?wt         TRUE         TRUE         NA
```

**Reference**

Cameron, A. C., & Windmeijer, F. A. (1996). R-squared measures for count data regression models with applications to health-care utilization. *Journal of Business & Economic Statistics, 14(2)*, 209-220.